# Java close unclosed img tag

Tags: java, jsoup, saxparser

I've a Java webserver that gets html from a REST service. 
I try to work on it using SAXParser which tells me that tags like img or area needs to be closed.
Unfortunately I get img tags like this

```
<img src="https://..." style="width: 600px; height: 676px;">
```

Which is fine for browsers but not for my Parser.
I use this on my content before parsing it

```
replaceAll("<\\s*([^\\s>]+)([^>]*)/\\s*>", "<$1$2></$1>").replaceAll("<\\s*(img|area)+((\"[^\"]*\"|[^>/])*)(?<!/)\\s*>", "<$1$2></$1>")
```

The first part is converting self closed tags to "real" closed tags. 
The second should close unclosed tags lke the img or area in my case.

I testet it [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) with some examples 
[image: Test Results]

It seems to work quite fine, but if the img is already closed its closed again

```
<area clas="" href=">" > </area> -->    <area clas="" href=">" ></area> </area>
```

Which I can't understand right now. Could you help me?
Maybe I even need to generalize it a bit more??

**UPDATE:**
I know that it's not right to use regex for html, however I need to send this to a piece of Code that I'm not allowed to change which is using XSLTransformation and there I get SAXParser error on selfclosing and unclosed tags. 
Is it possible to use jsoup to convert all unclosed or self-closing tags into closing ones and get that as output?

**UPDATE:**
Terrible... Obviously everything works with JSOUP.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
// Some additional cleanups
this.parentContent = doc.select("body").html();
```

And I get my HTML... I was just thinking to complex :-(

Comment: [Don't use regex on XML/HTML!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: The SAXParser is an XML parser. I would try an HTML parser like Jsoup (http://jsoup.org/) that has the same parsing behaviour as common browsers.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML and XML are not interchangeable formats, and you might see a whole bunch of different problems pop up if you try to shoehorn it.

I would suggest using a HTML parser (maybe http://jsoup.org/ ) instead of a SAX one in order to parse HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Add a lookahead and test if it is closed.If not then apply closure.

```
(?=regex1)regex2
```

Process regex2 only if regex1 matches.